# Why does printing a large number of copies take so long for CUPS to process?

Tags: cups

I needed to print 40 copies of a 21-page (2-sided) color PDF document. It took 40 minutes from the time I hit "print" to the time the printer started printing.

When I print one copy, it starts up much more quickly. It seems that the more copies I make, the longer the delay between when I hit print and when it starts printing. Why would that even be the case? Is CUPS sending a 840-page document to the printer? Shouldn't the printer just be accepting one file and "know" to make the copies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the printer just be accepting one file and "know" to make the copies?

That would require the printer to have enough RAM to a) store the whole document and b) still have enough free memory to render any single page of your print job in full resolution. And even if those things are true, CUPS needs to tell the printer to do it. If CUPS isn't sure the printer can do it, CUPS will indeed send a print job of 840 individual pages to the printer.

Another possibility would be to print the copies *uncollated*, i.e. first print 40 copies of the first 2-sided page, then 40 copies of the second 2-sided page, and so on. This would require the user to put each copy of the document together manually, which can be irritating and error-prone if there are many pages. That's why having the copies *collated* (i.e. first print all pages of copy #1, then all pages of copy #2, etc.) tends to be the default in modern printer drivers whenever possible.

Comment: Still, it would be more efficient to transmit the the document 40 times instead of combining it into one document of 40 times that size, because the printer could start after one minute with the first copy while waiting for the next transmission ...

Answer (score 1):

In my case it's an inefficiency in GhostScript.

I sent 100 copies of a single-page PDF document to my EcoTank inkjet from my old Raspberry Pi 1.  In the lengthy time before the printer started to receive data, the GNU/Linux `top` and `ps` commands on the Pi said nearly 100% of the CPU was doing this:

```
gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r360x360 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=841 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=0 -dcupsCompression=1 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c <</.HWMargins[8.400000 8.400000 8.400024 8.399963] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice -f -_
```

When I tried temporarily replacing `/usr/bin/gs` with a script that captured its input, I confirmed that CUPS had generated a 100-page PDF file (using `pdftopdf`) and had asked GhostScript to rasterize this.

In other words, CUPS asked GhostScript to convert 100 pages to bitmap.  CUPS didn't seem to know it could ask GhostScript to convert just one page and send that result to the printer 100 times, and GhostScript didn't seem to know it could have done *its* job by rendering just the first page and repeating that result 100 times.  GhostScript probably could have done a better job here, because the 100-page PDF file that CUPS made for it *did* tell it to *re-use* objects from the previous page 100 times, but GhostScript wasn't clever enough to do this without taking lots of CPU re-rendering them.

(And no it doesn't work to replace `/usr/bin/gs` with a script that calls the real GhostScript on one page and repeats its result 100 times: it will need low-level changes to its binary header to make CUPS accept the additional copies.)

If I instead create 100 separate print jobs with

```
for i in {1..100}; do lp doc.pdf; done
```

then it starts printing much more quickly, but there is a short delay between each copy as the Pi re-renders the page.  And if I instead create 20 print jobs of 5 copies each,

```
for i in {1..20}; do lp -n 5 doc.pdf; done
```

there is a longer delay between each batch of 5 while `gs` runs.  CUPS is apparently not advanced enough to start running `gs` on the next job before the first job has finished.

If we did a lot more work on the CUPS or GhostScript source code, we might be able to make it recognise this situation and reuse its computations more.  Unfortunately, that extra development would take us a lot more time than just waiting for it, or bypassing CUPS by connecting a machine that has software to drive the printer directly.